# Android: Auto fill edittext box data in WebView using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In my application I require that kind of functionality in which when I pass particular url,email and password to webview,And when given url load in webview,its edittext box must be fill with email,password.

But In my case I passed "http://www.facebook.com" url and want to fill facebook email address block  with abc@gmail.com,but facebook email address edittext box shows always blank when url load in webview.

For this, I have used following code:

```
web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webredirect);                                  
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

 @Override
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
            web.loadUrl("javascript: (function(){javascript:document.forms[0].elements[0].value = 'abc@gmail.com';}) ();" );
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: The  `edittext` which you want to update from js, is it created inside the `webview` widget ?

Comment: No I am just loading face book url in webview ,edittext is the control of facebook login form for mobile view